# using qgis and shaply error: GEOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer

Tags: python, qgis, shapely

I tried to create a polygon shapefile in QGIS and read it in python by shapely. An example code looks like this:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
multipolys = fiona.open(somepath)
multi = multipolys[0]
coord = shape(multi['geometry'])
```

The EOSGeom_createLinearRing_r returned a NULL pointer
I checked if the polygon is valid in QGIS and no error was reported. Actually, it does not work for even a simple triangle generated in QGIS. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Like J. P., I had this issue with creating LineStrings as well. There is [an old issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/353) (2016) in the Shapely github repository that seems related. Changing the order of the imports solved the problem for me:

```py
from shapely.geometry import LineString
import fiona 

LineString([[0, 0], [1, 1]]).to_wkt()
# 'LINESTRING (0.0000000000000000 0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000 1.0000000000000000)'
```

whereas

```py
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import LineString

LineString([[0, 0], [1, 1]]).to_wkt()
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 48, in __init__
#     self._set_coords(coordinates)
#   File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\shapely\geometry\linestring.py", line 97, in _set_coords
#     ret = geos_linestring_from_py(coordinates)
#   File "shapely\speedups\_speedups.pyx", line 208, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linestring_from_py
# ValueError: GEOSGeom_createLineString_r returned a NULL pointer
```

Some other issues in the Shapely repository to look at

- [553](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/553#issuecomment-369206763) for import order issues on a Mac
- [887](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/887) (same reverse-import-order trick with `osgeo` and `shapely`)
- [919](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely/issues/919)

Comment: Incredible this did it - omg *why* fiona devs?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem but with the shapely.geometry.LineString. The error I got was

```
ValueError: GEOSGeom_createLineString_r returned a NULL pointer
```

I don't know the reason behind this message, but there are two ways, how to avoid it:

1. Do the following:

   ```
   ...
   from shapely import speedups
   ...

   speedups.disable()
   ```

   Import the speedups module and disable the speedups. This needs to be done, since they are enabled by default.
   From shapelys speedups init method:

   ```
   """
   The shapely.speedups module contains performance enhancements written in C.
   They are automaticaly installed when Python has access to a compiler and
   GEOS development headers during installation, and are enabled by default.
   """
   ```

   If you disable them, you won't get the NULL Pointer Exception, because you don't use the C implementation, rather than the usual implementation.
2. If you call python in a command shell, type:

   ```
   from shapely.geometry import shape
   ```

   this loads your needed shape. Then load your program

   ```
   import yourscript
   ```

   then run your script.

   ```
   yourscript.main()
   ```

   This should also work. I think in this variant the C modules get properly loaded and therefore you don't get the NULL Pointer Exception. But this only works, if you open a python terminal by hand and import the needed shape by hand. If you import the shape with your program, you will run into the same error again.

Comment: The first solution works for me, but the script is about a half slower.

Answer (score 1):

Face the same issue and this work for me

`import shapely`

`shapely.speedups.disable()`

Answer (score 0):

I had roughly the same error, with a list of coordinates in a LinearRing.

```
  File "/app/app/main.py", line 5340, in __get_polygon
    if LinearRing(polygon).is_ccw:  # geojson want right-hand-rule for Polygon
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/shapely/geometry/polygon.py", line 54, in __init__
    ret = geos_linearring_from_py(coordinates)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "shapely/speedups/_speedups.pyx", line 346, in shapely.speedups._speedups.geos_linearring_from_py
ValueError: A LinearRing must have at least 3 coordinate tuples
```

```
shapely.speedups.disabled()
```

did the trick, however a better solution was to transform the list into a tuple:

```
LinearRing(tuple(polygon)).is_ccw
```